# Книга по PHP + Ajax + XML

Tags: php, книги

Какую можно почитать книгу по пхп, желательно что - то из нового и последнего.
Уровень знания достаточно высокий, просто давненько этим не занимался, а технологии не стоят на месте. )

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее полное на мой взгляд изложение php5 в книге Котерова - PHP5 в подлиннике (2 изд). 
Там он затрагивает и ajax и xml в частности. Будет полезна и новичкам и профи.
Также если интересует Ajax отдельно, то книжка Дари - AJAX и PHP изобилует всяческими примерами на этот счёт

Comment: а что - то более новое есть?

Comment: Real-World Solutions for Developing High-Quality PHP Frameworks and Application
Автор: Sebastian Bergmann, Stefan Priebsch
2011 года книга

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите узнать все возможности ООП для PHP:
Зандстра М.  PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования 
http://www.books.ru/shop/books/833011

Все про Ajax:
Пауэлл Т. Ajax. Полное руководство
http://www.books.ru/shop/books/708542

Общие вопросы:
Леон Шкляр, Рич Розен Архитектура веб-приложений
http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5656021/

Answer (score 0):

Для Ajax удобней использовать JSON формат. Он легче и понятней, чем XML. В JSON можно передавать массивы, объекты.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
Эти функции понимают только UTF-8 кодировку.

На стороне клиента получаете функцией
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
На выходе получаете уже готовый распарсенный массив.